# How can you reproduce the procedure that occurs when a Android market app is updated?

Tags: android

I have an app that reads and writes files during `onCreate`.  The problem is that when the app is installed via the Market and run the first time the files it needs to get have no access to them.  I get FileNotFound exceptions even though the file is there. If I back out of the app and reopen it then the files can be read.

This is not the same behavior when pushing the apk from eclipse or adb.  In fact I was able to reproduce the problem using eclipse and thought I fixed it doing adb uninstalls and eclipse installs but the problem persists for users pulling the update from the market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adb -d shell pm uninstall -k package.name lets you remove a package without removing the data files or cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you increase your CodeVersion, then build your apk (signed with the same cert as the previous market application), running
    adb -d install -r package.name
will install the application without removing the data.  It basically does an update. I believe using the -l option will ensure that the CodeVersion number is also of a greater value than is currently on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

- Increasing the `android:versionCode` in your AndroidManifest.xml
- Generating the apk
- `adb install name.apk`

Comment: This won't let you install over an existing installation.  `adb -d shell pm uninstall -k package.name` lets you remove a package without removing the data files or cache.  
I guess that's the best I can ask for. Thanks.